# Retrieving records from one table based in 'similar' values of another table

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I'm trying to come up with a select syntax for retrieving records from one table (B) based in 'similar' values of another unrelated table (A).

There are two tables:

```
TABLE_A
ID  CODE    COMPANY
1   234     XYZ Corporation, LLC
2   142     Corp ABC Enterprise, S.L.D.
3   145     Z. Incorporated, GmBH
4   134     XYZ Corporation, LLC
5   741     Z. Incorporated, GmBH
6   952     Corp ABC Enterprise, S.L.D.

TABLE_B
ID  COMPANY
1   XYZ Corporation
2   Z. Incorporated
3   Corp ABC Enterprise
4   Just another Company
```

I need to extract TABLE_B.COMPANY field from criteria existing in TABLE_A. For example, if search criteria is CODE=234, I need the result '*XYZ Corporation*' from TABLE_B.

TABLE_A has repeated companies, whereas TABLE_B has not.

So far I have this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT T1.COMPANY
FROM TABLE_A T1 WHERE EXISTS
(SELECT 1 FROM 
(SELECT CONCAT(T2.COMPANY, '%') AS Company FROM TABLE_B T2) c 
WHERE T1.COMPANY LIKE Company AND T1.CODE='234';
```

This yields the result '*XYZ Corporation, LLC*' whereas I need '*XYZ Corporation*'. That is, I need something like SELECT T2.COMPANY FROM ... which obviously does not work because that variable is unknown for the first SELECT.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `join` instead of `exists` to get the row from `table_b`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT T2.COMPANY
FROM TABLE_A T1 JOIN
     TABLE_B T2
     ON T1.COMPANY LIKE CONCAT(T2.COMPANY, '%') AND T1.CODE = '234'
```

Comment: Wow, fast response and exactly what i needed. Thanks!